# java/opengl: loading textures on 64bit VM

Tags: java, opengl, 64-bit, textures

it seems my texture loader doesnt work anymore when run in a 64bit environment. im not sure if the cause is the 64bit VM itself or if the file lying on a 64bit filesystem.

the image to load is a RGBA png file, it shows up correctly on 32bit windows systems, but on my 64bit win7 some color channels seem flipped.

here is my code:

```
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream(path);
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(is);
is.close();

byte[] databytes = ((DataBufferByte) bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(databytes.length);
data.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
data.put(databytes, 0, databytes.length);
data.rewind();

IntBuffer texb = IntBuffer.allocate(1);

binding.genTextures(1, texb);
binding.bindTexture(binding.TEXTURE_2D(), texb.get(0));
binding.texParameter(binding.TEXTURE_2D(), binding.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER(), 
    binding.LINEAR());
binding.texParameter(binding.TEXTURE_2D(), binding.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER(), 
    binding.LINEAR());
binding.texParameter(binding.TEXTURE_2D(), binding.TEXTURE_WRAP_S(), 
    binding.CLAMP());
binding.texParameter(binding.TEXTURE_2D(), binding.TEXTURE_WRAP_T(), 
    binding.CLAMP());
binding.texEnvi(binding.TEXTURE_ENV(), binding.TEXTURE_ENV_MODE(), 
    binding.MODULATE());
binding.texImage2D(binding.TEXTURE_2D(), 0, binding.RGBA(), bi.getWidth(), 
    bi.getHeight(), 0, binding.RGBA(), binding.UNSIGNED_BYTE(), data);
```

does anyone know what could be wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it turned out a problem with the latest update java6 u18 which contained some changes to bufferedimage and had nothing to do with 64bit VMs